# Як перекласти російське "случаем"?

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Наприклад, "Вы, случайно, не из Киева?", "Ты, случаем, уж не удушишся ли?"

На думку одразу спадає "випадком", але це, думаю, неправильно, неприродно.
Мабуть, треба перебудовувати речення.

Comment: В цих випадках підходить слово "раптом"

Answer (score 5):

[ЧАСОМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/chasom)

> **2.** Випадково, ненароком. *— Чи ви не п'яні **часом**, пане хазяїне, бодай ви здорові були? — поспитав він з непевністю в голосі* (Михайло Коцюбинський, I, 1955, 115); *Сафрон з підсвідомим острахом поглянув на вікно попівського будинку: чи не побачив його **часом** з кімнати начальник штабу* (Михайло Стельмах, II, 1962, 183); *— Вибачайте, у вас **часом** нема сірників?* (Олексій Кундзіч, Пов. і опов., 1951, 20).

[БУВА́](http://sum.in.ua/s/buva)

> **2.** *вставн. сл.* ...
>
> //  Уживається для вираження ймовірності чогось неприємного; чого доброго. *— Чи ти, **бува**, не здурів? чи не збожеволів, Чіпко?.. — гукає Лушня* (Панас Мирний, II, 1954, 205); — Нічогенька хмарка, — каже людина з йоржиком, — доки змалюєте, щоб, **бува**, не втопила... (Юрій Яновський, II, 1954, 197);
>
> //  Уживається для вираження припущення у знач., близькому до може. *А що, як спитаю, чи не треба їм, **бува**, коням овса або якого борошна?* (Квітка-Основ'яненко, II, 1956, 20); *— Що ж, коли їх доля так помежувала: одному дала багато, а другому — нічого... — Доля?.. Гляди лишень, Галю, чи доля то! чи не самі люди, **бува**, й винні?..* (Панас Мирний, II, 1954, 252);
>
> ...

Answer (score 2):

"раптом".

наприклад: "А ви, раптом, не з Києва"?

Answer (score 2):

Може подивувати, але *случай* існує в українській, в тому числї від класіків.

> [*Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 9, 1978. — Стор. 384.*](http://www.inmo.org.ua/sum.html?wrd=%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9)
>
> **СЛУ́ЧА́Й**, **случаю**, *чол.*, *розм.* Те саме, що [випадок](http://www.inmo.org.ua/sum.html?wrd=%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA) 1, 2.
>
> *Серце плаче, як згадаю Хоч невеселії случаї І невеселії ті дні, Що пронеслися надо мною* (Тарас Шевченко, II, 1963, 173); *Думка його, як він не одганяв її, знай вертілася коло того случаю з арфʼянкою* (Панас Мирний, III, 1954, 275); *[Шумейко:] От тобі й на! Нащо вже я передовик, а такого случаю за шістдесят сім років життя ще ніколи не бачив* (Іван Микитенко, I, 1957, 492); *Ніхто краще його не ставав до бою.. У тих-то случаях пошрамовано його вздовж і впоперек, що козаки, як прозвали його Шрамом, то й забули реєстрове його прізвище* (Пантелеймон Куліш, Вибр., 1969, 53); *— Значить, ти вже батько. По такому случаю і ми з тобою по чарупині випємо* (Михайло Стельмах, II, 1962, 73).
>
> **На (про) всякий случай** — те саме, що **На (про) всякий випадок** (*див.* [випадок](http://www.inmo.org.ua/sum.html?wrd=%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA)).
>
> *[Хлопець:] Ну, нащо ж ти се кажеш? [Дівчина:] На всякий случай…* (Леся Українка, II, 1951, 103); *Як вже дуже смертось, ввійшли в будинок; тоді в ньому було тільки чотири світлички: у двох жив сам пан, а дві пустували, про всякий случай, для гостей* (Олекса Стороженко, I, 1957, 184);
>
> **На случай чого** — те саме, що **На випадок** (*див.* [випадок](http://www.inmo.org.ua/sum.html?wrd=%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA)).
>
> *На голові [діда] соломʼяний бриль; на плечі, на герлизі, висить торба з хлібом та свита — на случай негоди* (Панас Мирний, I, 1949, 150).

Щоправда, позначене як *розмовне*. Що частково правдливо, бо має рїдкий вжиток або сприймають за діялектізм. Однак, слово — не московізм, бо зі таким значеннєм було ще в доукраїнські часи і можна зустрїти також в гинших мовах, що «далекі» від нас:

> [*Етимологічний словник української мови Інституту мовознавства ім. О. О. Потебні НАН України.*](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9#15652)
>
> давньоруська *лучитися* «трапитися», нижньолужицька *łucyś se* «траплятися», прасловʼянська *lučiti sę* «трапитися», сербохорватська *слу́чити се* «трапитися; потрапити», старословʼянська *лѹчити сѧ* «зустрітися, трапитися»

Можна подумати, що то московізм, бо приросток *с* замість сучасного *з*, якщо наступний звук — *л*. Але українська має чимало таких випадків, коли *с* збережено: *смітник*, [*свита*](http://www.inmo.org.ua/sum.html?wrd=%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0) (одяг), [*свинка*](http://www.inmo.org.ua/sum.html?wrd=%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0) (деревʼяний мʼяч) ітд.

---

Якщо однаково треʼ слово, то можу порадити, з не згаданих тут, [*випадково*](http://www.inmo.org.ua/sum.html?wrd=%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE), що є прямим відповідником до похідного від *случай* — *случайно*, котре, як на мене, не спотворює згадані вами речення.

Comment: Цікава ваша думка. Як гадаєте, чи піде українській мові на користь якщо ми почнемо вживати *случай* у значені *випадок*?

Comment: @Yola В цьому питаннї менї, якщо чесно, однаково. Якщо говориш свойою говіркою, котра має такого слова — продовжуй на здоровя! Зьвісно, _випадок_ красше звуче через відсутність такого _с_, а також є поширенїшим словом. Якщо ж говорити з суто етѵмолоґічного погляду, тобто надчистомовства, то _случай_ має певну перевагу, бо давнє слово, що переішло до української, а _випадок_ може бути запозикою з Ляської. Тож, відповідь залеже від того, як і що вкладаєш в _користь_.

Comment: Мені здається, що ви не зовсім праві кажучи, що *случай* сприймають за діалектизм, бо його здебільшого сприймуть за суржик.

Comment: А доукраїнські це які часи? І чому наявність слова в ті часи означає, що це не московізм?

Comment: @Yola 1) то є сумна правда, що значна частина люду, котра знайома лише з державною україською, сприймають будь-яке незвичне слово, пак схоже з сусїдними мовами, як суржик або полонізм, нп. ± подібна доля з _держати_, _ждати_ ітд; 2) коли були протодіялекти і ранїше; тут вже згадані як давньоруська (грубо: мова Русьи), а також старословʼянська. Чому не московізм? Бо тоді а) московської мови теж не було; б) українські говірки мусили би втратити слово геть, а потім перезапозичити, що такого, якщо поглянути на вжитки, не було.